# Why Angular 8 tooltip doesn't show properly

Tags: html, angular-material, angular8

I am trying to make tooltip by the following way:

```
   <span ntsTooltip="{{column.tooltip}}" tooltipPosition="top">
         <i class="material-icons info-icon">info</i>
   </span>
```

It works but the user has to be very much at the center of info incon to get the tooltip text visible. Also, tooltip text comes and quickly disappers.

I tried also following way:-

```
<span ntsTooltip="{{row.info}}" tooltipPosition="top">
  <i class="material-icons info-icon">info</i>
</span>
```

It has also similar kind of problem as mentioned above. How do I get a proper tooltip in Anguelr 8?

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't template bind in attributes, you should use attribute binding. [ntsTooltip]="column.tooltip" note the square brackets.

Comment: this change made no difference at all.

Comment: That is why it is a comment and not an answer. I was just pointing out that you are incorrectly binding to attributes rather than trying to solve your issue.